# Connecting a Docker Web App to a SQL Server instance that is also running in Docker

Tags: c#, .net, docker, episerver

My SQL Server databases are running fine as Docker containers and I am able to connect in SSMS, however when my web app attempts to connect to these SQL Server instances it fails. See exception error below:

```
EPiServer.Framework.Initialization.InitializationEngine[0]

      Initialize action failed for 'Initialize on class EPiServer.Data.DataInitialization, EPiServer.Data, Version=12.4.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=- - - -'

      Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

You can see my `docker-compose` file below:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  sql-commerce: 
    container_name: "sql-commerce"
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=Passw0rd123!
      - DB_NAME=commerce
    ports:
      - '1433:1433'
    volumes:
      - ./databases_project/files/data/commerce:/var/opt/mssql/data
  sql-cms:
    container_name: "sql-cms"
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=Passw0rd123!
      - DB_NAME=cms
    ports:
      - '8080:1433'
    volumes:
      - ./databases_project/files/data/cms:/var/opt/mssql/data
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      EcfSqlConnection: "sql-commerce"
      EPiServerDB: "sql-cms"
    ports:
      - '3080:80'
```

This then speaks to a `Dockerfile` in the same level:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build

WORKDIR /ProjectName
COPY ["Applications/Website.Src/Website.Src.csproj", "Website.Src/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Website.Src/Website.Src.csproj" --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --source https://nuget.optimizely.com/feed/packages.svc/
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/ProjectName/Applications/Website.Src"
RUN dotnet build "Website.Src.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Website.Src.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Website.Src.dll"]
```

My connection string looks like the following:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "EcfSqlConnection": "Server=localhost,1433;Database=projectCommerce;User Id=sa;Password=Passw0rd123!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True",
    "EPiServerDB": "Server=localhost,8080;Database=projectCms;User Id=sa;Password=Passw0rd123!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  },
```

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong here?

---

*Update*

I have attempted to target the sql container names rather than local host in my connection string, however even that fails to connect.

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "EcfSqlConnection": "Server=sql-commerce,1433;Database=projectCommerce;User Id=sa;Password=Passw0rd123!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True",
    "EPiServerDB": "Server=sql-cms,8080;Database=projectCms;User Id=sa;Password=Passw0rd123!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  },
```

Comment: in your container, localhost is the container, not the docker host machine.  Your connection strings should point to the sql container, not localhost.

Comment: Thanks I've tried replacing the server with `Server=sql-commerce,1433` and `Server=sql-cms,8080` respectively but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I just posted an answer with some more detail

Answer (score 0):

In your docker-compose, each container acts as its own host.  When you refer to `localhost` in your connection string, the web container sees this as itself, not the host (docker) machine.

You can make things complicated in docker-compose by setting up different networks too, but by default, your containers will all be on the same network.  I like to specify a host name for each container, like this:

```
services:
  sql-commerce: 
    hostname: sql-commerce
    container_name: sql-commerce
```

Then, you can use that name in your connection string.

You might also look at the difference between `ports` and `expose` if you don't want the sql services open to the host machine - `expose` allows you to keep them inside the docker network only.  Right now, I think you would need to specify port `1433` for both connections (internal to the docker network) where the second one is only listening on `8080` on the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot communicate between containers using localhost. Using localhost inside a container will only point to itself.

Docker has a DNS server built in and containers can connect between each other using the container name like you did, but **your database names is still wrong** in your example, according to your compose file they should be commerce and cms.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "EcfSqlConnection": "Server=sql-commerce,1433;Database=commerce;User Id=sa;Password=Passw0rd123!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True",
    "EPiServerDB": "Server=sql-cms,8080;Database=cms;User Id=sa;Password=Passw0rd123!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
},
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the `docker-compose` file to match the database name in the connection string, however I am still failing to connect.

Comment: @nathano can you test too ping between the containers, use this from the console `docker exec -ti sql-cms ping sql-commerce`, and more importantly can you ping from your website container `docker exec -ti Website ping sql-commerce`, replace `Website` with the relevant container name.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, try removing the port from the connection string as follows:

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "EcfSqlConnection": "Server=sql-commerce;Database=projectCommerce;User Id=sa;Password=Passw0rd123!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True",
    "EPiServerDB": "Server=sql-cms,8080;Database=projectCms;User Id=sa;Password=Passw0rd123!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  },
```